# How can I force a schema replacement operation in LDAP

Tags: ldap, apache-ds

I am using ApacheDS. I have created a custom schema such that it is in its own container under schema. When I make changes to the LDIF file and re-import it, I keep getting errors indicating that the MODIFICATION REQUEST failed.

As long as I go in an manually delete each of the entries in that hierarchy, I can subsequently import the LDIF.

Is there a setting, parameter, keyword I can add to the LDIF file that forces the server to delete the existing components before attempting to add the new ones, or to simply replace existing entries?